# add list view webpart on one site collection home page from one another site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

we have a requirement to add a web part from one site collection List to another site collection home page

is this possible OOTB Way?

any help will be appreciatd

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think its possible using **Content Search Webpart**. here is the Micrsoft help link reagrding Content Search Web part.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-a-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-0DC16DE1-DBE4-462B-BABB-BF8338C36C9A.

You can Customize Content Search Webpart using Display Template if you want so.